# jquery load content from another part of site with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, load

i want to make my site ajax with jquery.
example:
when click on a link like this: /category/blabla.html,
the content of `#container` of this link goes to the another id like `#CONTENT`.
and the script must have a loading img like this: http://www.ajaxload.info/.
thanks for your support and sorry for my bad english!

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is your question? It sounds more like someone ordering a happy meal...

Answer (score 0):

```
  **THIS IN YOUR HTML(FOR THE IMAGE)**
    <div id="loading">
    <!-- this is the loading gif -->
    <img src="your image">
    </div>
  **THIS IS THE POSSIBLE LINK**
    <a onclick="return yourAjax(this);">Link</a>    

  **THIS IS YOUR (POSSIBLE) SCRIPT**
    function yourAjax(link) {
        $('#loading').show();
        $.ajax({
        url: "test.html",
        context: document.body
        }).done(function(response) {
        $(link).id("CONTENT");
        $('#loading').hide();
        $('#CONTENT').html(response) // response assumed to be html
        });

    }

HOPE THIS HELPS TO GIVE SOME IDEA!!
```